# Три варианта: «Тёмные века», Тёмные века и тёмные века, - что выбираем?

Tags: прописная-строчная, кавычки

> А за так называемые *тёмные века* богословами, поэтами и теологами
>   кропотливо вырабатывается и ход литургии, и гимны, и молитвы, и
>   правила расположения храмовых мозаик, фресок, скульптуры.

Курсив авторский.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так думаю, это имеется в виду конкретная историческая эпоха,значит, с прописной буквы, как и Смутное время, Петровская эпоха, позднее Возрождение, Высокое Возрождение, Серебряный век русской поэзии. В кавычках исторические эпохи не пишут, если только: Он употребил название "Тёмные века" - здесь как бы указание на условность - не сама эпоха, а её название.

*А за так называемые Тёмные века богословами, поэтами и теологами кропотливо вырабатывается и ход литургии, и гимны, и молитвы, и правила расположения храмовых мозаик, фресок, скульптуры.*

Comment: Грамота.ру тоже рекомендует с прописной.

Answer (score 2):

**А за так называемые "тёмные века" богословами, поэтами и теологами кропотливо вырабатывается и ход литургии, и гимны, и молитвы, и правила расположения храмовых мозаик, фресок, скульптур.**

Это не имя собственное (период неточен, не обозначен чётко определенными событиями). Понятие это условное, и его достаточно часто заключают в кавычки и пишут со строчной буквы, хотя варианты встречаются разные. И уж никак к имени собственному не подойдет выражение ***так называемый***.

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F2%B8%EC%ED%FB%E5%20%E2%E5%EA%E0&p=0

Средневековье, темные века — не существенное и не точное именование. [В. В. Бибихин. Язык философии (1993)]

Розенталь:  Примечание. При словосочетании ***так называемый*** последующие слова в кавычки не заключаются. Исключение составляют случаи, когда эти слова употреблены в **необычном** или ироническом значении.

Интересно, что термин "тёмные века" употреблялся по отношению к разным историческим периодам: эти ***тёмные века*** были в России, были в Греции, были между бронзовым и железным веками и т.д. Получается, что античный мир, средневековье, феодализм пишутся со строчной буквы, а непонятные ***темные века*** с прописной. **Где логика?**